# Please I need to select city calling which has number of KM travelled is greater than 1000

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

```
select CITY_CALLING 
sum(DISTANCE_KM)
from REAL_TRIP join
     SOURCE_CITY
     on SOURCE_CITY.city_id = REAL_TRIP.city_id
group by 1
```

```
 city_CALLING   |         sum         |
 Visakhapatnam  | 14.5920725980000014 |
 Hyderabad      | 2759.24699709970082 |
 San Diego      | 87.3699351497999999 |
 Moscow         | 984.947118170600447 |
 Alexandria     | 8.96134862429999934 |
 Prague         | 86.0471747345999916 |
 Recife         | 20.7398930000000021 |
 Leeds          | 140.606494992300014 |
 Copenhagen     | 14.7657918324999997 |
 Fresno         | 29.6572209023999989 |
 Tijuana        | 61.7240377603999946 |
 Baton Rouge    | 7.05829104329999968 |
 Krasnodar      | 296.730780097399986 |
 Sochi          |  237.51827971039998 |
 Cincinnati     | 116.423747349400003 |
 Guwahati       | 1057.34938192379968 |
 Champaign      |  6.8250736618000003 |
 Vienna         | 1180.11211812669899 |
 Charlotte      | 150.293475570500021 |
 Raleigh-Durham | 152.720579113999946 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select CITY_CALLING
sum(DISTANCE_KM)
from REAL_TRIP join
SOURCE_CITY
on SOURCE_CITY.city_id = REAL_TRIP.city_id
group by 1
HAVING SUM(DISTANCE_KM) > 10000;